# Vectorization of an R function

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm fairly new to R and I want to vectorize an user defined function of two or more arguments; I managed to do it only for one arg.

The function I want to vectorize is the following:

```
c <- function(x, y, z){
  ifelse(x**2 + sin(y) <= z, x - z + exp(y) <= 1, FALSE) 
}
```

If I put inside three different vectors (x,y,z) I only get one vector as output; how can I something like a multidimensional output? Because neither `mapply` nor `Vectorize` are doing their job.

Comment: Please give a specific complete reproducible example of input and corresponding expected output.

Comment: To name a function or any other object `c` is a really bad idea, it already is an R function.

Comment: Your `ifelse` has two logical conditions and only one alternative value.  That is probably why you can't vectorise it!  `ifelse` is already a vectorised function if used properly.

Comment: Name your function `cc` and try `lapply(1:3, function(x) outer(1:4, 1:5, cc, x))`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar It seems that the second logical condition is the `yes` (logical) value. And the `no` value is `FALSE`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes indeed, that makes sense!